# Calling nested Function onClick event not recognizing nested functions

Tags: javascript, html

Getting `not defined` error on console when calling nested functions with `onClick` event in the html page. I tried searching for answer on other posts but was not able to. I am thinking it is a scope or closure issue. But not quite sure how to fix it.

I have html pulling in an external .js file and have the following functions below.
I call the main function `mySelection1` in the `checkMySelection` function. And call the nested functions within `mySelection1` on the main html on `onClick` events. The goal is to change the `currentPage` variable depending which button they click (it is initially declared as a global var in the beginning of the .js file.)

```
//first function
 function mySelection1() { 
  alert("in mySelection1 function");
  var SubMenu1 = function() {
    currentPage = 1;
    alert("current XML node is " + currentPage);
  };
  var SubMenu2 = function() {
    currentPage = 2;
    alert("current XML node is " + currentPage);   
  };
  var SubMenu3 = function() {
    currentPage = 3;
    alert("current XML node is " + currentPage);   
  };
}
//second function
function checkMySelection() {

  SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
  VariableArray = SearchString.split('=');
  mySelection = VariableArray[1];
  console.log(mySelection); 

  switch (mySelection) {
    case '1':
      alert("Case 1");
      mySelection1();
    break;
    case '2':
      //alert("Case 2");
      //mySelection2();
    break;
    default:
      alert("Something went wrong...");
  }
}

<! -- CODE IN HTML BELOW -->

<button id="defaultItem" class="menuItem active" onclick="openItem(event, 'item1'); SubMenu1()">Item 1</button>
          <button class="menuItem" onclick="openItem(event, 'item2'); SubMenu2()">Item 2</button>
          <button class="menuItem" onclick="openItem(event, 'item3'); SubMenu3()">Item 3</button>
```

Looks like the nested functions are being ignored altogether... :/ What am I missing? And is there a better approach?

****UPDATE BELOW****
Hello all, looking at modern pattern for a solve to the original post... I am starting with the following instead of the nested function in a function approach...

```
//Using Object Literal Notation
var mySelection1 = {
  mySubMenu1: function() {
    currentPage = 1;
    alert("current XML node is " + currentPage);
  },
  mySubMenu2: function() {
    currentPage = 2;
    alert("current XML node is " + currentPage);   
  },
  mySubMenu3: function() {
    currentPage = 3;
    alert("current XML node is " + currentPage);   
  }
}
```

I understand to call the functions I have to use mySelection1.moduleSubMenu1(); mySelection1.moduleSubMenu2 (); and mySelection1.moduleSubMenu3(); I added these to my html page buttons... since I only want them called upon button onClick event.

```
<button id="defaultItem" class="menuItem active" onclick="openItem(event, 'video'); mySelection1.moduleSubMenu1()">Video</button>
<button class="menuItem" onclick="openItem(event, 'resources'); mySelection1.moduleSubMenu2()">Resources</button>
<button class="menuItem" onclick="openItem(event, 'quick-check'); mySelection1.moduleSubMenu3()">Quick Check</button>
```

This works very well if I am just using this one object... however, it brings me to the issue I am trying to accomplish (why I tried using the nested functions earlier)... how can I make the same var object reusable? The 'currentPage' var index value has to change depending what 'card' they came from (context in the comments of this post)... I need to have another object with the same functions to be able to change the 'currentPage'... i.e.

```
    //Second object needed
    var mySelection2 = {
      mySubMenu1: function() {
        currentPage = 6;
        alert("current XML node is " + currentPage);
      },
      mySubMenu2: function() {
        currentPage = 7;
        alert("current XML node is " + currentPage);   
      },
      mySubMenu3: function() {
        currentPage = 8;
        alert("current XML node is " + currentPage);   
      }
    }
```

This is fine, but the problem is that I want to use the same sub menu items, and they already have the previous object.function on the onClick...

```
<button id="defaultItem" class="menuItem active" onclick="openItem(event, 'video'); mySelection1.moduleSubMenu1()">Video</button>
<button class="menuItem" onclick="openItem(event, 'resources'); mySelection1.moduleSubMenu2()">Resources</button>
<button class="menuItem" onclick="openItem(event, 'quick-check'); mySelection1.moduleSubMenu3()">Quick Check</button>
```

Comment: When you define the functions `SubMenu1` inside another function like you have, they exist only in the scope of the enclosing function. They don’t exist outside. It’s not clear why they are nested in the first place.

Comment: But the nested functions (`SubMenu1`, etc.) are not *visible* outside `mySelection1`. You need something like a [module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) perhaps and namely the Revealing Module Pattern to expose them. Even then, I'm not sure what the goal here is. The whole approach with functions nested into others seems wrong.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thank you this validates my suspicion of it being a scope issue. Here is what I want to accomplish: the main home page has multiple 'cards' that the user can click on for more information. Depending on their selection, I am changing the value of the 'mySelection' var and passing it to the newly opened content page they selected. The 'checkMySelection' function reads the value and runs switch and calls the functions (mySelection1--provided in the sample code & will have other functions accordingly i.e. mySelection2, mySelection3) which will contain the same sub menu nested functions.

Comment: @MarkMeyer (continued) These are then called on the html button onClick event. I have the global ‘var currentPage’ declared in the beginning of the .js file… the nested sub menu functions will change the value of ‘currentPage’ to the corresponding XML node index that will populate the xml content dynamically. But because of it being a scope issue it is not working once it gets to the nested functions.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you! I will look into it and give it a try :)... hopefully the context in my comments above paints a better picture of my logic.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot in your code that isn't declared so it's a bit hard to debug it. However there are a few problems with your syntax, here's the code.

```
         //first function
     function mySelection1() {
         alert("in mySelection1 function");

         function SubMenu1() {
             currentPage = 1;
             alert("current XML node is " + currentPage);
         }

         function SubMenu2() {
             currentPage = 2;
             alert("current XML node is " + currentPage);
         }

         function SubMenu3() {
             currentPage = 3;
             alert("current XML node is " + currentPage);
         }
     }
     //second function
     function checkMySelection() {

         SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
         VariableArray = SearchString.split('=');
         mySelection = VariableArray[1];
         console.log(mySelection);

         switch (mySelection) {
             case '1':
                 alert("Case 1");
                 mySelection1();
                 break;
             case '2':
                 //alert("Case 2");
                 //mySelection2();
                 break;
             default:
                 alert("Something went wrong...");
         }
     }
     var button1 = document.getElementById("defaultItem");
     button1.addEventListener("click", SubMenu1);
```

Comment: Thank you, 'currentPage', 'mySelection', 'SearchString' and 'VariableArray' are global vars declared at the beginning of my .js file. These all work accordingly, but the nested functions are ignored. From what I saw in the previous comments looks like it is a scope issue. (The html sample code for the button element I provided lives in my html document)